# Why is my aos (animation on scroll) package working in some elements and not in other ones?, vue3 proyect

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, animation, frontend

I'm working on a Vue3 project, for my needs the "aos" library was suitable, nevertheless I'm having issues with the implementation, practically all the HTML el in which I declare: `data-aos="fade-up"`( just an example ) => end up fading. I saw the exact moment when it slowly fades.
It's strange becauuse in my Hero Image the  and the  below work correctly:

```
<template #title
        ><h1
          class="text-3xl w-full font-bold text-white sm:text-6xl sm:w-screen"
          data-aos="fade-up"
          data-aos-duration="1000"
        >
          {{ t('homeHero.title') }}
        </h1></template
      >
      <template #subtitle
        ><p
          class="w-full mt-4 sm:leading-relaxed text-white sm:text-xl sm:w-screen"
          data-aos="fade-up"
          data-aos-duration="1000"
        >
          {{ t('homeHero.desc') }}
        </p></template
      >
```

But, if i do the exact same in a button el below:

```
        <a
          class="block w-full px-8 py-3 text-md font-medium text-white rounded-xl shadow bg-accent sm:w-auto focus:outline-none focus:ring"
          :href="`${appDomain}`"
          data-aos="fade-up"
          data-aos-duration="1000"
        >
          {{ t('homeHero.buttons.join') }}
        </a>
```

It just dont work.

And I already tried these 2 ways of init.
on my main.ts:

```
const app = createApp({
  render: () => h(App),
  mounted() {
    AOS.init()
  }
})
```

and like this:
Home.vue

```
    onMounted(() => {
      AOS.init()
      AOS.refresh()
    })
```

this is the Hero Component, which contains both elements, h1, p, and button..

```
<template>
  <section class="relative bg-black">
    <slot name="img" />

    <div
      class="hidden sm:block sm:inset-0 sm:absolute sm:bg-gradient-to-r sm:from-black sm:to-transparent"
    ></div>

    <div
      class="relative max-w-screen-xl px-4 py-32 mx-auto lg:h-screen lg:items-center lg:flex"
    >
      <div class="max-w-xl text-center flex flex-col self-end sm:text-left">
        <slot name="title" />

        <slot name="subtitle" />
        <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-4 mt-8 text-center">
          <slot name="link" />
          <slot name="buttons" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

Comment: Is there any `v-if` or conditional rendering in any parent element of the `button`?

Comment: No, there's not.

Comment: Could you provide the component, that `button` exist in, and its parent components if there, Or could you reproduce the issue on a live code editor like codesandbox, so we can debug and help you?

Comment: Ya, i share the Component... Thank u!